# Any way to use custom function defined in the dialect in the @Formula or @CustomTransformer annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to support Redshift and Clickhose. I have two dialect extensions:

```
public class RedshiftDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    public RedshiftDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("to_date",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                        StandardBasicTypes.DATE,
                        "to_date(to_char(?1, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')"));
    }
}

public class ClickHouseDialect extends Dialect {

    private static final LimitHandler LIMIT_HANDLER =
        new AbstractLimitHandler() {
            @Override
            public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
                final boolean hasOffset = LimitHelper.hasFirstRow(selection);
                return sql + (hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supportsLimit() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean bindLimitParametersInReverseOrder() {
                return true;
            }
        };

    public ClickHouseDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "Nullable(String)");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "Nullable(Int64)");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "Nullable(Date)");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "Nullable(DateTime)");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "Nullable(Float64)");
        registerFunction("to_date",
                new StandardSQLFunction(
                        "toDate",
                        StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
    }

    @Override
    public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
        return LIMIT_HANDLER;
    }
}


public class RedshiftDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    public RedshiftDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("to_date",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                        StandardBasicTypes.DATE,
                        "to_date(to_char(?1, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')"));
    }
}
```

Here is my entity mapping:

```
@Immutable
@Entity(name = "ReportEntry")
@Table(name = "reporting")
public class ReportEntry implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Dimension
    @Formula("to_date(date)")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant date;
    ...
}
```

I'd like to that whenever I mention date attribute in my hql the to_date(date) expression evaluated depends on current dialect, but unfortunately @Formula annotation accepts only native SQL expression. Any ideas how use custom function with formula?

Comment: AFAIK, Formula is pure SQL, while the dialect functions only work in HQL.

Answer (score 0):

You probably better implement a custom type instead.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type

(You probably find tutorials which are a better resource to implement your own type).

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It actually doesn't solve much of your problem. AFAIK, custom types do not provide much abstraction in queries, so you still need the function there. In the mapping, you replace the formula by the custom type. If you have many of these kind of columns, it may be a bit easier. With a custom type, you get better control of caching and you can write to the column (while a formula is a read-only column). If all this doesn't sound much useful to you, then custom types are not appropriate.